# Clicked Button CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, button

I've got a stubborn button on my page created using the input tag

```
<input class="my-button" type="button" value="Go to Page" onclick="window.open(href='https://example.com');" />
```

I've got CSS for this button for its normal state and :hover state working just fine.

```
input.my-button {}

input.my-button:hover {}
```

Now when the button is clicked, the colour is changed to my theme's default button colour. ( although other styling remains as per my CSS, it's just the colour that's changing )

I've tried adding more CSS for other stages such as

```
:visited
:clicked
:active
```

together with the !important element, but none of the above seems to work.

Is there any other button state I should be putting in?

Comment: How about `:focus` ?

Comment: *"Now when the button is clicked"* - Do you mean while the mouse button is still down, or after the mouse button is released?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an input tag for a button, use `<button>` or `<a>`, `<a>` will most likley work better in your favour. 
You can use padding to make it appear like a button, just add `padding: 20px` for example. Then style to however you please. If you would like it beveled like a button, simply add ..

```
    box-shadow:inset 0px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), /*bottom internal shadow*/
                 inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8); /*top internal highlight*/
```

You should then be able to use `:active` or `:focus` effectively. Your hover will not be effected as long as you change the `<input>` to `<a>` in the CSS